# How to catch Windows LogIn and Logoff using JNA

Tags: java, events, jna

I need to catch the windows logIn and Log off events to run/stop schedulers in Java.

I read we can do this by using JNA, I have searched a lot but couldn't get any clear picture(I never worked with JNA before).

Could anyone please tell me how can I start a scheduler when a user logs In to Windows and stops it when User Logs off from windows using JNA?

Comment: http://code.dblock.org/jna-reading-windows-event-log-entries-in-java

Comment: You'll need to find a reference or example in native code first, *then* you can figure out how to translate that into JNA.